# Certain values resulting in infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a Javascript calculator for energy calculations, and it mostly works but certain numbers cause the browser tab to crash. My jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qdjfrjLr/

Try entering an 8 for any day's discharge time or a 15 for any time at all.

I suspect the problem relates to my loop (under the 'do the loop' comment) but I can't see the problem. The purpose of the loop is to determine what value liq_capacity needs to be in order to get fri_ending_balance to (or near) 0.

```
function calculate() {
    // user inputs
    var sat_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('sat_charge').value);
    var sat_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('sat_discharge').value);
    var sun_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('sun_charge').value);
    var sun_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('sun_discharge').value);
    var mon_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('mon_charge').value);
    var mon_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('mon_discharge').value);
    var tue_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('tue_charge').value);
    var tue_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('tue_discharge').value);
    var wed_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('wed_charge').value);
    var wed_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('wed_discharge').value);
    var thu_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('thu_charge').value);
    var thu_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('thu_discharge').value);
    var fri_charge = parseInt(document.getElementById('fri_charge').value);
    var fri_discharge = parseInt(document.getElementById('fri_discharge').value);
    // back-end variables
    var sys_power_rating = 100;
    var noak = 1;
    var efficiency = 60; // expressed as a percentage
    var tank_escalation_factor = 0.9;
    var liq_reference_cost = 16300000;
    var experience_coefficient = 0.175; // expressed as a decimal
    var liq_reference_size = 300;
    var liq_and_pru_escalation_factor = 0.6;
    var power_recovery_reference_cost = 5705000;
    var power_recovery_reference_size = 3.5;
    var tank_coldstore_reference_size = 100;
    var liq_plant_specific_work = 0.2;
    var cost_of_tank_and_coldstore = 41;
    var pru_specific_work = liq_plant_specific_work * (efficiency / 100);
    if (liq_plant_specific_work < 0.1) {
        var tank_coldstore_reference_cost = cost_of_tank_and_coldstore * tank_coldstore_reference_size * liq_plant_specific_work;
    } else {
        var tank_coldstore_reference_cost = cost_of_tank_and_coldstore * tank_coldstore_reference_size * 0.1;
    }
    // do the loop
    var liq_capacity = 1;
    var fri_ending_balance = 1;
    while (fri_ending_balance < -0.1 || fri_ending_balance > 0.1) {
        var sat_initial_balance = 0;
        var sat_production = sat_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var sat_consumption = -1 * sat_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var sat_ending_balance = sat_initial_balance + sat_production + sat_consumption;
        var sun_initial_balance = sat_ending_balance;
        var sun_production = sun_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var sun_consumption = -1 * sun_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var sun_ending_balance = sun_initial_balance + sun_production + sun_consumption;
        var mon_initial_balance = sun_ending_balance;
        var mon_production = mon_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var mon_consumption = -1 * mon_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var mon_ending_balance = mon_initial_balance + mon_production + mon_consumption;
        var tue_initial_balance = mon_ending_balance;
        var tue_production = tue_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var tue_consumption = -1 * tue_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var tue_ending_balance = tue_initial_balance + tue_production + tue_consumption;
        var wed_initial_balance = tue_ending_balance;
        var wed_production = wed_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var wed_consumption = -1 * wed_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var wed_ending_balance = wed_initial_balance + wed_production + wed_consumption;
        var thu_initial_balance = wed_ending_balance;
        var thu_production = thu_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var thu_consumption = -1 * thu_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        var thu_ending_balance = thu_initial_balance + thu_production + thu_consumption;
        var fri_initial_balance = thu_ending_balance;
        var fri_production = fri_charge * liq_capacity / 24;
        var fri_consumption = -1 * fri_discharge * sys_power_rating / pru_specific_work;
        fri_ending_balance = fri_initial_balance + fri_production + fri_consumption;
        liq_capacity = liq_capacity + 0.1;
    }
    var power_input = liq_capacity / 24 * liq_plant_specific_work;
    var liq_store_capacity_tonnes = Math.max(sat_production, sat_ending_balance, sun_production, sun_ending_balance, mon_production, mon_ending_balance, tue_production, tue_ending_balance, wed_production, wed_ending_balance, thu_production, thu_ending_balance, fri_production, fri_ending_balance);
    var liq_store_capacity_mwh = sys_power_rating * Math.max(sat_discharge, sun_discharge, mon_discharge, tue_discharge, wed_discharge, thu_discharge, fri_discharge);
    var liq_store_capacity_mwh_effective = tank_coldstore_reference_size * pru_specific_work;
    var liq_ecurve = liq_reference_cost * (Math.pow(noak, (Math.log(1-experience_coefficient)/Math.log(2))));
    var pru_ecurve = power_recovery_reference_cost * (Math.pow(noak, (Math.log(1-experience_coefficient)/Math.log(2))));
    var tank_and_coldstore_ecurve = tank_coldstore_reference_cost;
    var liq_cost_dollars = liq_ecurve * Math.pow((liq_capacity / liq_reference_size), liq_and_pru_escalation_factor);
    var pru_cost_dollars = pru_ecurve * Math.pow((sys_power_rating / power_recovery_reference_size), liq_and_pru_escalation_factor);
    var tank_and_coldstore_cost_dollars = (tank_and_coldstore_ecurve * 1000) * Math.pow((liq_store_capacity_tonnes / tank_coldstore_reference_size), tank_escalation_factor);
    var capex = liq_cost_dollars + pru_cost_dollars + tank_and_coldstore_cost_dollars;
    var cost_kw = capex / (sys_power_rating * 1000);
    var cost_kwh = capex / (liq_store_capacity_mwh * 1000);
    // slap those results on the page
    document.getElementById('liq_capacity').value = (liq_capacity).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('power_input').value = (power_input).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('liq_store_capacity_mwh').value = (liq_store_capacity_mwh).toFixed(0);
    document.getElementById('efficiency').value = efficiency + '%';
    document.getElementById('capex').value = (capex / 1000000).toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById('cost_kw').value = (cost_kw).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('cost_kwh').value = (cost_kwh).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that does the calculation here. I think the problem is in your `while` loop. Your variable `fri_ending_balance` probably stays either below `-0.1` or above `0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - here you go. It's quite a bit (I actually removed a lot from my real one) so didn't want to clutter up the page too much, hence the jsfiddle :-)

Edit: sorry about posting it the wrong way - I just use guest account for asking stuff on here! This way at least means my initial post doesn't become insanely huge.

(Code dump added to question.)

Edit: Many thanks w3d! The stupid thing is that I used to have a wider range of acceptable results (-0.9 to 0.9) but changed it to get a more accurate result. Anyway it's all running nicely now, so thank you for the help :-) And nope, no email notifications! I just hit refresh from time to time.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting this code in an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25262245/edit

Comment: @Sam You seem to have created a brand new user here on StackOverflow (which means you can't edit your question!), rather than use your existing account on StackExchange? (Although you've not actually registered ... hhmmm, not sure how that works then?)

Comment: @Sam, By using _another_ guest account you won't be able to comment on other answers, mark answers as excepted, get notified of responses (do you get notified?), etc. etc. Anyway, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is with your loop:

```
while (fri_ending_balance < -0.1 || fri_ending_balance > 0.1) {
```

When you specify a value of `9` for a days "Discharge" then the value of `fri_ending_balance` never gets near enough to 0 to satisfy your loop condition. Specifically, `fri_ending_balance` never becomes >= -0.1 and <= 0.1, so your loop never ends.

If you log these results to the console you can see what is happening:

```
Iteration  fri_ending_balance
71418      -0.5999999802772891
71419      -0.36666664694234896
71420      -0.1333333136069541    /* Should stop here */
71421       0.10000001972525752
71422       0.3333333530601976
71423       0.5666666863955925
71424       0.8000000197278041
```